# In mysql, what is the different about perfomance between int and float data type?

Tags: php, mysql, types

I have a value of the floating-point number which required precision up to 2 fractional digits. This value will be stored in MySQL database. I want to optimize database performance, so I think that it should be converted to whole number by multiplying by 100 before saving it to integer field. However, I must convert back when using it on the application level (PHP language). That also consumes CPU performance. Most of the calculations are done on application level.

Is this a effective method? Does it speed up reading/writing the value to database?

Comment: No, it's not. Performance optimizations only make sense based on prior profiling and benchmarking, not guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the number as a float in the database - there is basically nothing to be gained by storing it as an integer and converting it later.  The only reason this might ever make sense is if you had tens or hundreds of thousands of inserts every second, and even then, converting a float into binary takes much less CPU time compared to writing a new row to disk.

Answer (score 1):

A float is probably the *wrong* way to store the value.  The correct way is to use `decimal`, which is designed for fixed length decimal values.  So, use something like `decimal(18, 2)`, if you want two digits after the decimal place.

Read about the fixed point types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html).

Do not use a float if you care about precision and want to use equality.

Comment: But I afraid the query speed is decreased.

Comment: @vutaviva . . . You should store the number in the appropriate form in the database.  If you need exactly two digits of precision, then you should store it that way.  If you need it to replicate a floating point value in php, then you should store it that way.  However, your question starts with two digits of precision.